# How to escape line breaks using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a value extracted from my database table which contains characters like `"` `'` `<` `>` and line breaks also, now I want to pass it to a jQuery variable like this

```
var str = "<?php echo $str; ?>";
```

But I always get an error in my console.log because of these characters and the line breaks. Please how can I fix this using jQuery?

Comment: No, I don't know what is Babel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiline strings are not supported by most browsers. Therefore, you probably need to fix the string in your PHP.

If you are targeting new browser versions, you can try to use backticks:

```js
var str = ` This is a 
multiline string supporting brackets, quotes and single quotes:

" " "

' ' '

<> {} ()

` // only the backtick will end the string

console.log(str);
```

---

As you can see on MDN, the browser support is pretty minimal though.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```
Feature         Chrome  Edge    Firefox (Gecko) Internet Explorer   Opera   Safari
Basic support   41      (Yes)   34 (34)         No support          28      9
```

Comment: What happens if a server-side string contains a backtick?

Comment: @raina77ow Exactly what the comment said, it will end the string. That will be causing errors. They need escaping.

Comment: Sorry to say, but this just isn't right. PHP's `json_encode` gives out a valid JS literal, so one doesn't have to escape or replace anything. Not only backticks-based approach is not supported by IE11 (that's a minor issue these days), it also can easily break on backticks or any escaping symbols within the string literal. So I suggest at least mentioning `json_encode` based approach in your answer.